# Why don't most criminal convictions also come with an additional charge of making a false claim to law enforcement?

Tags: criminal-law

It appears that the vast majority of suspects proclaim their innocence to police at some point in the process (while being arrested, during an interview, etc)

Later, many of these people admit their guilt through a confession and/or guilty plea. Also some are proven guilty in court.

Are all of these people charged with making a false statement?  If not, why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why aren't all guilty people charged with perjury](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/19139/why-arent-all-guilty-people-charged-with-perjury)

Comment: No, the law I'm referring to is not lying under oath it is making a false statement to a police officer. The answer to that question doesn't seem to explain this one

Comment: @N00b101 I don't see such an offense in the New York criminal code.  Do you have a particular jurisdiction in mind, and, if it's New York, can you point out the relevant section of the penal law?  There _is_ such an offense in US federal law, and as far as I understand people are charged with committing that offense on a regular basis.  But lying to a state officer doesn't violate the federal law.

Comment: This relates, bur significantly different from the linked question, and should not be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @phoog in addition to the federal law there's the example of California Vehicle Code 31.